# What is an updated index configuration of Google Firestore in Datastore mode?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

Since Nov 08 2022, 16h UTC, we sometimes get the following DatastoreException with code: UNAVAILABLE, and message:

```
Query timed out. Please try either limiting the entities scanned, or run with an updated index configuration.
```

I want to get all Keys of a certain kind of entities. These are returned in batches together with a new cursor. When using the cursor to get the next batch, then the above stated error happens. I am expecting that the query does not time out so fast. (It might be that it takes up to a few seconds until I am requesting the next batch of Keys using the returned cursor, but this never used to be a problem in the past.)

There no problem before the automatic upgrade to Firestore. Also counting entities of a kind often results in the error DatastoreException: "The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable."

I am wondering whether I have to make any changes on my side. Does anybody else encounter these problems with Firestore in Datastore mode?

What is meant by "an updated index configuration"?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: Please post some example code & queries?  Often updated index configuration means to use a composite index instead of relying on a merge join query plan..

Comment: For count(), are you using the new aggregate count query (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/aggregation-queries) or count() using a large offset as built into some client libraries?

Comment: Regarding the first error: It is an inequality query over one field (a date and time field) of all entity-keys of a fixed kind (e.g. "all entity-keys of kind K such that 'lastUpdated' < X"). There is no composite index specified, but there is no need for it, right?

Comment: Regarding the count-error: Thanks for the hint with the new aggregate count query. I will check that.

Comment: Without evidence of what you are doing after your query, I'd guess a delete, so you might be hitting tombstones, and can now use strong consistency to avoid your problem (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#avoid_skipping_over_deleted_data).  That said, if the cursor is being used correctly, you shouldn't be hitting tombstones on later queries.

Comment: The entities of kind K have an indexed timestamp T ('lastUpdated') and most of them have values within a 6h timespan, so very close together. I want to update all entities every 24h, so once a day I query for all entities of K, s.t. T<X. where 'X=24h ago'. Actually I query for the first 10000 entity-keys, roughly like this:

(1) Cursor cursor = null;
(2) Query query = new KeyQuery.Builder().setKind("K").setLimit(10000).setFilter("T<X").setStartCursor(cursor).build();
(3) DatastoreReaderWriter.run(query);

Then I update the Cursor in (1) and redo (2)+(3). And in (3) I get the error.

Comment: Of the entity-kind K are 3.3 million entities in the datastore. Each time the 10000 keys are returned, I create an update-task U for each returned key. There are no deletes of entities of kind K. But there are many writes, and these writes change the values of the indexed timestamp T. The reason is that the update-tasks U's are executed parallely and each of them saved the updated entitiy with T being set to the actual server-time.

Comment: The aggregation count works if I don't specify any filter, i.e. counting all entites of kind K, but when counting all entities of kind K, such that T<X, I get a similar error as before "com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Aggregation query timed out. Please try either limiting the entities scanned, or run with an updated index configuration."

Comment: This is how I do the aggregation count which returns the error: 
PropertyFilter filter = PropertyFilter.lt("T", Timestamp.of(X));
EntityQuery entityQuery = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder().setKind("K").setFilter(filter).build();
AggregationQuery aggregationQuery = Query.newAggregationQueryBuilder().addAggregation(Aggregation.count().as("count")).over(entityQuery).build();
AggregationResults aggregationResults = datastore.runAggregation(aggregationQuery);
Long aggregationCount = Iterables.getOnlyElement(aggregationResults).get("count");

Comment: You certainly seem to be hitting tombstones on the lastUpdated timestamp.  I'd guess from your description that you want to ensure all 3.3 million entities are updated each day, but a lot of them get updated anyway through normal operations.  So it's these normal updates that leave a bunch of tombstones that the cursor isn't able to avoid quickly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wanted to follow up here since we were able to do detailed analysis and come up with a workaround. I wanted to record our findings here for posterity's sake.

The root of the problem is queries over large ranges of deleted keys. Given schema like:

Kind: *ExampleKind*

Data:

| Key | lastUpdatedMillis |
| --- | --- |
| ExampleKind/1040 | 5 |
| ExampleKind/1052 | 0 |
| ExampleKind/1064 | 12 |
| ExampleKind/1065 | 100 |
| ExampleKind/1070 | 42 |

Datastore will automatically generate both ASC and DESC index on the `lastUpdatedMillis` field.

The the `lastUpdatedMillis ASC` index table would have the following logical entries:

| Index Key | Entity Key |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ExampleKind/1052 |
| 5 | ExampleKind/1040 |
| 12 | ExampleKind/1064 |
| 42 | ExampleKind/1070 |
| 100 | ExampleKind/1065 |

In the workload you've described, there was an operation that did the following:

1. `SELECT * FROM ExampleKind WHERE lastUpdatedMillis <= nowMillis()`
2. For every ExampleKind Entity returned by the query, perform some operation which updates `lastUpdatedMillis`
3. Some of the updates may fail, so we repeat the query from step 1 again to catch any remaining entities.

When the operation completes, there are large key ranges in the index tables that are deleted, but in the storage system these rows still exist with special deletion markers. They are visible internally to queries, but are filtered in the results:

| Index Key | Entity Key |
| --- | --- |
| x | xxxx |
| x | xxxx |
| x | xxxx |
| 42 | ExampleKind/1070 |
| ... | Und so weiter ... |
| x | xxxx |

When we repeat the query over this data, if the number of deleted rows is very large (100_000 ... 1_000_000), the storage system may spend the entire operation looking for non-deleted data in this range. Eventually the Garbage Collection and Compaction mechanisms will remove the deleted rows and querying this key range becomes fast again.

A reasonable is workaround is to reduce the amount of work the query has to do by restricting the time range of the `lastUpdateMillis` field.

For example, instead of scanning the entire range of `lastUpdateMillis < now`, we could break up the query into:

1. `(now - 60 minutes) <= lastUpdateMillis < now`
2. `(now - 120 minutes) <= lastUpdateMillis < (now - 60 minutes)`
3. `(now - 180 minutes) <= lastUpdateMillis < (now - 120 minutes)`

This example uses 60 minute ranges, however the specific "chunk size" can be tuned to the shape of your data. These smaller queries will either succeed and find some results, or scan the entire key range and return 0 results, however in both scenarios they will complete within the RPC deadline.

Thank you again for reaching out about this!

A couple notes:

1. This deadlining query problem could occur with any kind of query over the index (projection, keys only, full entity, etc)
2. Despite what the error message says, no extra index here is need or would speed up the operation. Datastore's built-in ASC/DESC index over each field already exists for you and is serving this query.